# Bug/Feature/Faulty while script in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, alias

I found a cool script on tecmint:

```bsh
while true; do echo "$(date '+%D %T' | toilet -f term -F border --gay)"; sleep 1; done
```

and tried to alias it in my .zshrc as what-time like so:

```bsh
alias what-time = "while true; do echo "$(date '+%D %T' | toilet -f term -F border --gay)"; sleep 1; done"
```

The problem is that when i reload zsh and enter what-time, instead of the desired output, this shows up:

```
while>
```

It is an endless prompt and to me it seems like it doesn't execute the body of `while`. Can someone please help?

BTW i use Arch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape both the quotes `"` by doing `\"` and the dollar sign operators `$` by doing `\$`. Furthermore, you musn't leave spaces between `alias`, `=`, and the code. (Instead of `alias foo = "foo"`, do `alias foo="foo"`)

Therefore your command to alias

```
while true; do echo "$(date '+%D %T' | toilet -f term -F border --gay)"; sleep 1; done
```

to

```
what-time
```

is

```
alias what-time="while true; do echo \"\$(date \"+%D %T\" | toilet -f term -F border --gay)\"; sleep 1; done"
```

Comment: The spaces where just a coding habit on the question here. Thanks for the solution